# HTML why is my nested class a sibling and not a child

Tags: html, css

I'm sure there are similar questions out there but I haven't been able to find a conclusive answer.  I have an HTML script with nested divs:

```html
<ul id="navbar">
  <li><a href='#' class='dropdown'>Rules</a>
    <div class='rules'>
      <ul>
        <li>Rules Explanation Here</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I believe that the div class 'rules' is a child of the class 'dropdown'.  However when I was working on my css file, I couldn't get a hovering action on the dropdown class to effect my rules class unless I used the ~ connector.

This works in my CSS file:

```
.dropdown:hover ~ .rules{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

But this does not work:

```
.dropdown:hover .rules{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

As I understand it the ~ should only work if the classes are siblings which I do not believe they are.

Could someone explain why these classes are siblings here or link me to an easy to understand explaination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its correct, because `.rules` is child of the `li` but not the `a.dropdown` that you have as well as child of the `li`, therefore 2 children make them siblings

#### Snippet with `.rules` as sibling

```css
.dropdown+.rules {
  border: red solid/* only affect the first sibling */
}

.dropdown~.rules {
  background: yellow/* afects all siblings */
}
```

```html
<ul id="navbar">
  <li><a href='#' class='dropdown'>Rules</a>
    <div class='rules'>
      <ul>
        <li>Rules Explanation Here</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class='rules'>
      <ul>
        <li>Rules Explanation Here</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

#### Snippet with `.rules` as child

```css
.dropdown .rules {
  border: red solid;
  background: yellow
}
```

```html
<ul id="navbar">
  <li><a href='#' class='dropdown'>Rules
    <div class='rules'>
      <ul>
        <li>Rules Explanation Here</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a fully indented version of your code, which I think will help you visualize the answer better:

```html
<ul id="navbar">
  <li>
    <a href='#' class='dropdown'>Rules</a>
    <div class='rules'>
      <ul>
        <li>Rules Explanation Here</li>
        <li>Second list item</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

First of all, let's explain the difference between the concepts:

- **parents and children** are in different levels. The `li` is a child of
  the `ul`. `ul` is the parent.
- **siblings** are children of the same parent, and are always at the same
  level. The innermost `ul` has 2 children `li` (in my example, not yours). And those children `li` are siblings.

So what happens with `.dropdown` and `.rules`? They are both children of the same `li` element. Notice that the `a.dropdown` is opened and closed before `.rules` starts. So they are children of the same parent, and as in real life, that makes them siblings.

Answer (score 0):

It is because your class `.dropdown` is a clas of a tag and inside a tag you only have text "Rules". Element that has class `.rules` is nested inside li element not a. 
To achieve what you want, do this

```
<li class='dropdown'>
  <a href='#'>Rules</a>
    <div class='rules'>
      <ul>
        <li>Rules Explanation Here</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</li>
```

With css that you wrote without ~ sign.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.parent{
  padding: 20px;
  background:tomato
  }
.dropdown{
  background: yellow
 }
 .rules{
 padding: 15px;
 background: green
 }
 .grandchildren{
 background: blue
 }
```

```html
  <ul id="navbar">
      <li class="parent">
        <a href='#' class='dropdown'>Dropdown - children 1</a>
        <div class='rules'>
          Rules - Children 2
          <ul class="grandchildren">
            <li>Rules Explanation Here</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

It is a **sibling combinator** case where the logic takes place within the same parent element, both `.dropdown` and `.rules` are children of `li` which makes them `siblings`. *General sibling combinator doesn't need to immediately succeed the first element but can appear anywhere after.* For more info, check out >> https://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```css
ul#navbar {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
ul#navbar li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
ul#navbar li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}
div.rules {
  display: none;
  min-width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 102%;
  background: lightblue;
  
}
div.rules ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
div.rules li {
  float: none;
}
div.rules ul li a {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}
.dropdown:hover > .rules {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul id="navbar">
  <li class='dropdown'><a href='#' >Rules</a>
    <div class='rules'>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" >Rules Explanation Here</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```